# Error while looping through an array of structs

Tags: c, struct

I'm writing an FFT in C for the Parallax Propeller, and it won't compile. I assume it's a problem with how I'm using structs (I'm new to C, translating all this from Clojure), but I can't even isolate the problem to work on it. Removing certain segments of the code allows it to compile but I can't make heads or tails of it. I've looked up everything I can on structs and arrays and now I need more help! Thanks!

The compiler error is posted at the end.

```
#include "simpletools.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "complex.h"
void fft();
int pow2(int exp);  // Added to fix one of two problems

float complex ibi[256];


int main(void)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
  ibi[i] = 1.0 + 1.0 * I;
  } 
}

void fft()
{
  int log2n = 8;
  int length = 256;
  float pi = 3.1415;  
  for(int i = 0; i< log2n; i++)
  {
    int n1 = pow2(i);
    int n2 = pow2(i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j< n1; j++)
    {
      for (int k = j; k < length; k= k + n2)
      {
      int k2 = k + n1;

      float complex dw, nw, df, nf;
      float da = pi * j / n1;
      float na = pi * (n1 + j) / n1;

      dw = cos(da) + -sin(da) * I;
      nw = cos(na) + -sin(na) * I;      

      df = ibi[k2] * dw;
      nf = ibi[k2] * nw;

      ibi[k2] = ibi[k] + nf;
      ibi[k]  = ibi[k] + df;

   }
   }
 }
}

int pow2(int exp)
{
  int answer = 2;
  for(int i = 0; i< exp; i++)
    {
    answer = answer * 2;
    }
  return answer;
}
```

Error while compiling:

```
propeller-elf-gcc -v GCC 4.6.1 (propellergcc_v1_0_0_2261)
propeller-elf-gcc -I . -L . \
    -I /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Utility/libsimpletools \
    -L /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Utility/libsimpletools/cmm/ \
    -I /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Text Devices/libsimpletext \
    -L /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Text Devices/libsimpletext/cmm/ \
    -I /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Protocol/libsimplei2c \
    -L /home/steffan/Documents/SimpleIDE/Learn/Simple Libraries/Protocol/libsimplei2c/cmm/ \
    -o cmm/ECG2.elf -Os -mcmm -Wall -m32bit-doubles -fno-exceptions -std=c99 \
    ECG2.c -lsimpletools -lsimpletext -lsimplei2c -lsimpletools -lsimpletext \
    -lsimpletools
/tmp/ccdKeRAK.o: In function `.L9':
(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `_cexpf'
/tmp/ccdKeRAK.o: In function `.L9':
(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `_cexpf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Done. Build Failed!

Check source for bad function call or global variable name `_cexpf'
/tmp/ccdKeRAK.o: In function `.L9':
(.text+0xba):
```

Comment: what the simpletoo.h contains ?

Comment: This sounds like a missing package. A quick google search on `undefined reference to '_cexpf'` also indicates that.

Comment: Is the `math.h` you are including a local file in your source code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page if you've not already done so.  Fixing the `pow2()` problem is easy - as [user3121023](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331627/error-while-looping-through-an-array-of-structs#comment37612660_24331627). The `_cexpf()` problem is trickier, not least because `.L7` isnt' a valid function name and there isn't self-evidently a reference to it in the code. C99/C11 has `<complex.h>` which has support for complex arithmetic and mathematics; are you sure you can't use that?

Comment: Thank you - I changed the Propeller simpleIDE compiler settings and now it works! Appreciate the help!

Comment: I wonder what happens if you drop the `-m32bit-doubles` option.  GCC 4.6.1 and its support library is just old enough that the trouble could be that the single-precision complex C functions are not available.  `_cexpf()` is the complex (`c`) exponential (`exp`) function for `float complex` (`f`); the leading underscore is simply a common addition to indicate an external function.  You might switch to use `complex` instead of `float complex`, at least to see the scope of the problem.